# Why I can't set Jenkins environment variable with Microsoft Azure Service Principal secret?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I try to factorize the use of my Azure credentials inside my Jenkins pipeline. Instead of using withCredentials inside each stage of my pipeline I would like to initialize it into one environment variable. I use Azure credentials plugin (version 4.0.6) and my Jenkins is in version 2.263.4.2.

I read the plugin documentation https://plugins.jenkins.io/azure-credentials/#plugin-content-declarative-pipeline and despite of that I met an issue:

```
ERROR: No suitable binding handler could be found for type com.microsoft.azure.util.AzureCredentials. Supported types are StandardUsernamePasswordCredentials,FileCredentials,DockerServerCredentials,StringCredentials,AmazonWebServicesCredentials,SSHUserPrivateKey.
```

It seems to be an error with secret type but in the plugin documentation, it does not seem to be a problem.

Did anyone ever try to use environment block in addition with credentials and Azure Service Principal secret please?

1. I created a Jenkins secret with Microsoft Service Principal type.
2. I implemented my Jenkins declarative pipeline code:

```
pipeline {
    agent { 
        node {
            label 'your_node_label'
        }
    }

    options {
        ansiColor('xterm')
    }

    environment {
        ARM = credentials('my_credentials_id')
    }

   stages {
            
        stage('Terraform Init'){
          steps {
             sh """  
                echo "Test"
             """           
          }
        }
    }
    post {
      always {
        cleanWs()
      }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to update the plugin version to the version 2.263.4.2. In fact I was using the plugin version 4.0.6 and this secret initialization feature thanks to credentials plugin has been introduced in 216.ve0b_4a_485ffc2 version. You can find the question I asked on the Github plugin: https://github.com/jenkinsci/azure-credentials-plugin/issues/155#issuecomment-1339628355

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).